Python code executing when app is shut down?
I have a python application in flask that has a function which requests data from the Instagram graph API and saves them in a database in intervals of 43200 second (12 hours). It then saves the result of the query (either SUCESS or ERROR) in a text file along with a time-stamp and the specification of the error if the request fails. When the request fails, I send an email using the simplegmail library to my gmail account to notify me of the error.
The function seems to be working fine. However, every day at around 18:30 I get an Error email from my app (even when the app is not running), saying that my request failed and that the error is [Errno 32] Broken pipe. How is this possible? Is my function running even when my app is not? I'm struggling to resolve the issue. Below is a snippet of code that handles the periodic requests.
def my_scheduled_task():
    with app.app_context():  # Push the app context
        file_path = "static/instagram_api_log.txt"
        token_record = Token.query.first()

        if token_record:
            access_token = token_record.access_token

            params = {'access_token': access_token}
            user_data_df = get_media(source_url, page_id, params)

            if user_data_df is not None:
                try:
                    save_media_to_database(user_data_df)

                    missing_days_profile_visits_len = check_for_missing_dates(ProfileVisit)
                    profile_views_data = get_profile_views(source_url, page_id, params, missing_days_profile_visits_len)
                    save_profile_visits(profile_views_data)

                    missing_days_profile_reach_len = check_for_missing_dates(ProfileReach)
                    profile_reach_data = get_profile_reach_per_day(source_url, page_id, params,
                                                                   missing_days_profile_reach_len)
                    save_profile_reach(profile_reach_data)

                    profile_follows_data = get_follows_per_day(source_url, page_id, params)
                    save_profile_follows(profile_follows_data)

                    success_message = "SUCCESS!"
                    current_time = datetime.now()
                    with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
                        # Append the current date and time to the file
                        file.write(str(current_time) + " " + success_message + "\n")

                except Exception as e:
                    error_message = f"ERROR! - Unknown error occurred in {e.__class__.__name__}: {str(e)}"
                    current_time = datetime.now()
                    with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
                        # Append the current date and time to the file
                        file.write(str(current_time) + " " + error_message + "\n")

                    admin_emails = User.get_admin_emails()
                    for email in admin_emails:
                        send_mail(email, "Instagram API Query Error", str(current_time) + " " + error_message + "\n")

            else:
                error_message = "ERROR! - get_media function returned None!"
                current_time = datetime.now()
                with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
                    # Append the current date and time to the file
                    file.write(str(current_time) + " " + error_message + "\n")

                admin_emails = User.get_admin_emails()
                for email in admin_emails:
                    send_mail(email, "Instagram API Query Error", str(current_time) + " " + error_message + "\n")

        else:
            error_message = "ERROR! - No access token found! Check the database or update your auth token!"
            current_time = datetime.now()
            with open(file_path, 'a') as file:
                # Append the current date and time to the file
                file.write(str(current_time) + " " + error_message + "\n")

            admin_emails = User.get_admin_emails()
            for email in admin_emails:
                send_mail(email, "Instagram API Query Error", str(current_time) + " " + error_message + "\n")


# Create a scheduler instance
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# Call the task immediately for debugging purposes
my_scheduled_task()

# Add a job to the scheduler
scheduler.add_job(my_scheduled_task, IntervalTrigger(seconds=43200))

# Start the scheduler
scheduler.start()


Please, provide detail, 'I get an Error email from my app ....' is pretty useless in order to provide reasoned feedback, How is the app run, is it running continuously ... ?. Presume you are aware tasks run asynchronously so scheduled jobs run in separate threads to the main thread ...
